# Windows 10 machine in WORKGROUP workgroup reports "NotJoined" in Windows Discovery Service

Tags: windows, workgroup, autodiscovery

I have a machine on my LAN (call it MACHINE-NAME) that is set in workgroup WORKGROUP. I believe this is the standard now for Windows 10, it's a pretty recent install and I haven't done any particular modification of the networking/services/etc. All the other Windows machines on my network show up in the Explorer Network tab except for this one. Wireshark reports that it responds to Windows Discovery Service messages with this as part of the reply for the `wsdp:Relationship/wsdp:Host/pub:Computer` key:

```
<pub:Computer>
    MACHINE-NAME/NotJoined
    </pub:Computer>
```

The docs [here](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-PBSD/%5BMS-PBSD%5D.pdf) seem to suggest that this means the machine believes it is no domain joined or part of a workgroup, but the System section of the Control Panel suggests this is not true.

Both the Function Discovery Provider Host and Publication services are running on the machine. It can access all other machines on the network correctly via \\PC-NAME\. I can access this machine from all other machines via \\MACHINE-NAME\, it just doesn't populate in the Network node like every other machine on the network (these machines do report `OTHER-MACHINE/Workgroup:WORKGROUP` in WDS messages).

Any ideas why this machine reports this way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on network discovery. Go to settings and type "network discovery" into the search bar, then enable it. You might have to bounce the machine(reboot) after you enable it.

Comment: Network Discovery is on on the machine (and persists through reboot). It finds all the other machines on the network. It responds to discovery messages. As far as I can tell, the only difference between it and the other machines it responds with "NotJoined" instead of a workgroup, which appears to make it not show up for other machines in explorer's network window.